# How can Unity set a reference of a transform to null after destroying the gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform tf = null;
    GameObject go = null;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        go = new GameObject();
        tf = go.transform;
        DestroyImmediate(go);
    }
    float t = 0;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        if(t > 2)
        {
            Debug.Log(go);
            Debug.Log(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how could Unity set tf null while it is a strong reference to an object. For example, the print of the reference a in the code following is not null,

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    class A
    {

    }
    class B
    {
        public A a = new A();
    }
    A a = null;
    B b = null;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        b = new B();
        a = b.a;
        b = null;
        GC.Collect(); //clear object b
    }
    float t = 0;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        if(t > 2)
        {
            Debug.Log(b);//null
            Debug.Log(a);//not null
        }

    }
}
```

I do know that the underlying implementation of Unity is in C++, but how could C++ collect all reference in C# pointing to a block of memory and set them all to null after the block of memory is deleted? There is no way in C# that we can delete an object manually like 'delete' keyword in C++ or set references to null.

Comment: They use a trick, they don't actually set it to null, but they override the equality operator to return that it is equal to null anyway.

Comment: You can check by comparing tf to null using `ReferenceEquals`

Answer (score 0):

In Unity or any managed environment like C#, memory management is handled by a garbage collector (GC). When an object is no longer referenced, it becomes eligible for garbage collection, where the GC will eventually reclaim its memory.

The behavior you're observing with the Transform reference being null after destroying the associated GameObject might seem counterintuitive, but it's due to the way Unity handles object destruction and the underlying garbage collection.

In your first example:

```
void Start()
{
    go = new GameObject();
    tf = go.transform;
    DestroyImmediate(go);
}
```

When you call DestroyImmediate(go), you're destroying the GameObject immediately. Unity's DestroyImmediate function not only destroys the GameObject but also releases its associated components (like the Transform). Even though you still have a reference to tf, Unity internally manages the destruction process, and the Transform reference becomes invalid/null because the object it was referencing no longer exists.

Regarding your second code example, in C#, you cannot explicitly trigger garbage collection using GC.Collect() for specific objects. The garbage collector works in the background, and while it can be suggested to collect garbage using GC.Collect(), it's ultimately up to the runtime when and how it does so.

In your second example:

```
void Start()
{
    b = new B();
    a = b.a;
    b = null;
    GC.Collect(); //clear object b
}
```

Even though you set b to null and trigger garbage collection, the reference a still points to the instance of A because a = b.a; sets a to reference the same object that b.a is referencing. Setting b to null doesn't affect the reference a holds to the object created earlier.

In C#, you don't manually deallocate memory or nullify references as you might do in languages like C++. Instead, the garbage collector automatically manages memory by tracking references and reclaiming memory when objects are no longer reachable.

Unity's behavior with managing object destruction might make some references appear null even if they were assigned previously. This behavior is specific to Unity and how it manages objects and their associated components during destruction.